# (Qt c++) Точка входа в процедуру _ZdaPvj не найдена в библиотеке DLL ...\Qt5Cored.dll

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, dll, clion

Я только начал изучение Qt. Написал простую (элементарную) тестовую программу:

```
int main() {
    QString string = QString("It is QString!");
    cout << string.toStdString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В редакторе clion она выполняется нормально (выводит "It is QString!")
Но при попытке запустить exe файл возникает ошибка:

[image: Точка входа в процедуру _ZdaPvj не найдена в библиотеке DLL ...\Qt5Cored.dll]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Не стоит пытаться запустить дебажную сборку (на это  указывает суффикс d в окончании названия библиотеки). А вообще почитайте про развертывание приложений Qt, например: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 5):

В каталоге с Qt (не QtCreator, а именно Qt нужной версии) в папке bin есть утилита windeployqt.exe. Запустите её, и она скопирует нужные файлы:

```
windeployqt.exe "путь_к_exe_файлу_приложения".
```

Подробнее про развертывание qt-приложений : https://habrahabr.ru/post/262211/

Answer (score 3):

в текущий каталог поместите qt-ые dll-ки вашей версии: ОС находит другую версию dll и их использует.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее для отладочной сборки так:

windeployqt.exe --debug "путь_к_exe_файлу_приложения"

Для релиза:

windeployqt.exe --release "путь_к_exe_файлу_приложения"

windeployqt подтягивает только библиотеки Qt. Могут ещё потребоваться ещё какие-либо, необходимые для clion. Можно просто запускать и смотреть, на что ругается и потом копировать библиотеки в папку с exe, либо посмотреть зависимости утилиткой (Dependency Walker), тогда покажет все зависимости для приложения.